# Unable to create database path file:/user/hive/warehouse Error

Tags: linux, hadoop, mapreduce, hive, hdfs

I have a 3 nodes cluster and I am getting following error while running some HIVE query

> FAILED: Error in metadata: MetaException(message:Unable to create
>   database path file:/user/hive/warehouse/db_dut.db, failed to create
>   database db_dut) FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask

My hive-site.xml contains following property

```
       <property>
      <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
      <value>jdbc:derby:;databaseName=/var/lib/hive/metastore/metastore_db;create=true</value>
      <description>JDBC connect string for a JDBC metastore</description>
    </property>

<property>
  <name>hive.metastore.warehouse.dir</name>
  <value>/user/hive/warehouse</value>
  <description>location of default database for the warehouse</description>
</property>
```

**>jdbc:derby:;databaseName=/var/lib/hive/metastore/metastore_db;create=true<** is correctly present at my local machine.

When i gave hadoop fs -ls /user/hive ..following output came

```
[root@scaj02bda01 metastore]# hadoop fs -ls /user/hive
Found 1 items
drwxrwxrwx   - hive hive          0 2013-04-09 01:40 /user/hive/warehouse
[root@scaj02bda01 metastore]#
```

The default database location for warehouse is correctly mentioned in HDFS with all read write execute permission, but still i am getting the same error.

Comment: What is the value of fs.default.name property in your hadoop core-site.xml.
Also. have you set the HADOOP_HOME env variable?
Also, post which hive version are you using ?

Answer (score 3):

It says it is unable to open database /var/lib/hive/metastore/metastore_db,this error normally comes when you dnt have permission to access the database.
Use below commond then reply me:

1)SUDO chmod -R 777 /VAR/LIB/HIVE/METASTORE/METASTORE_DB

2)chmod -R a+rwx /var/lib/hive/metastore/metastore_db

3) rm /var/lib/hive/metastore/metastore_db/*.lck

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, the problem was that the namenode not started in hadoop. 
Go to hadoop file and execute the following command:

```
.sbin/start-all.sh
```

after that check if the namenode started using

```
jsp
```

if not, I can refer to the following answer that helped me [Hadoop "Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive)" warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48978480/hadoop-permission-denied-publickey-password-keyboard-interactive-warning/50348467)

Once you make the namenode starts, your issue will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same error. I couldn't change the permissions because of the certain policies set. So, I created a new my own folder like `/hdp/myapp/warehouse` and specified that path in `hive-site.xml` as follows. This helped me to solve the issue.

```
<configuration>
  <property>
     <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
     <value>jdbc:derby:;databaseName=/hdp/myapp/warehouse/metastore_db;create=true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.metastore.warehouse.dir</name>
    <value>/hdp/myapp/warehouse/</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your hive-site.xml for the property hive.metastore.warehouse.dir. Point to the hdfs directory not local filesystem directory. So something like localhost:8020/user/hive/warehouse. That did it for me.