# Hadoop "Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive)" warning

Tags: hadoop, ssh, installation

I am following [this](https://isaacchanghau.github.io/2017/06/27/Hadoop-Installation-on-Mac-OS-X/) tutorial to install Hadoop in my computer. After finishing the installation, when I try to launch Hadoop using this command `./start-dfs.sh`, it returns me the following:

```
U:sbin U$ ./start-dfs.sh
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
localhost: U@localhost: Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive).
Starting datanodes
localhost: U@localhost: Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive).
Starting secondary namenodes [U.local]
U.local: U@pc.local: Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive).
2018-02-25 14:52:15,505 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
```

I tried un-installing and installing it several times to re-check if I missed something but still I keep getting this error at the end. After looking in some online forums I came to find that the last warning : `WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform` is not a big deal because it gives the error when we run Hadoop in a 64 bit machine. Will you please let me know what the other two error mean and how to fix them ? I have tried many solutions posted in the internet.

Comment: That's a warning, not an error. `Permission denied` is the error, and you didn't setup passwordless ssh correctly. For example, `ssh localhost` should not ask for a password

Comment: Thank you! It solved the problem.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Problem is when you are trying to ssh to a server (in this case localhost) it tries to authenticate you using your credential. And stores that info. But here password-less authentication is not configured, so each time you try to ssh, it will ask you for your password, which is a problem if *`machines try to communicate with each other`* using ssh. So to setup passwordless ssh, we need to add user machine's public key to server machines *`~/.ssh/authorized_keys`* file. In this case, both the system are same machines.

**So Long story short run the following command.**

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Comment: Is it a must to use `id_rsa.pub` as name of my key? How to specify the key I want to use?

Comment: Not mandatory . `cat ~/.ssh/myrsafile.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` :)

Comment: No I mean in Hadoop. I created a key named id_rsa_hadoop. I can added it to authorized_keys and config file in .ssh. I can `ssh localhost` without password but when I boot up data node it is not working with `Permission denied` error message

Comment: Did you restart your ssh-agent after creation ? https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/

Comment: Yes I have and that's why I can ssh local host without password

Comment: when we ssh localhost, we actually don't set up a TCP connection with localhost from localhost. The connection never hits NIC. So no encryption, hence no password.

Comment: No. The reason why I need to generate a new RSA key is because I originally tested `ssh localhost` and it prompts me for password. After replacing with a new only without passphrase it does not ask me for password any more but I need to specify with ssh key to use for ssh-ing to all host with the original ssh key. Never mind then. I will solve this problem myself

Answer (score 29):

Proceed with the following steps:

1. Generate new keygen.

   ```
   ssh-keygen -t rsa -P '' -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa
   ```
2. Register key gen:

   ```
   cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
   ```

Comment: While Sapy's answer describes in detail what exactly issue is, kayV's answer directly attacks the root cause. The only point I would like to add here, if 'authorized_keys' is not present in .ssh folder just do a vi and create an empty file with this name.

Answer (score 6):

```
cd hadoop/etc/hadoop
nano hadoop-env.sh
```

And paste this line in hadoop-env.sh

```
export HADOOP_SSH_OPTS="-p 22"
```

Answer (score 4):

I did the following 3 steps to create the password less login

1. ssh-keygen -t rsa (Press enter for each line)
2. cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
3. chmod og-wx ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

Comment: thx. I already done 1 and 2 and it wasn' work but when i do 3 it work

Answer (score 1):

Those who are still struggling with this error, my answer could help them.
If you have done everything right and have already added keys in authorized_keys as well, then all you need to do is to remove your id_rsa and id_rsa.pub (whatever names you have used for the keypair file) and empty your authorized_keys, in short just take a rollback, because you might have given a password while generating rsa key.

So just do one thing, create again the RSA key by:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

**Give the name of the file(when prompted): < your_filename >**

**And then do not give it a passphrase and rather just simply hit Enter**, i.e, leave it blank and thus you will never see the permission denied error (It worked in my case.)